# The type or namespace name 'PointOfService' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Tags: c#, .net, namespaces

I've added the Microsoft.PointOfService.dll to my project's references and VS even resolves its member classes correctly, however, when I try to build, I get the title error:

> The type or namespace name 'PointOfService' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

My code follows:

```
using Microsoft;
using Microsoft.PointOfService;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

    namespace oposfordotnet
    {
        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            PosExplorer explorer = new Microsoft.PointOfService.PosExplorer();
            CashDrawer drawer;
        }
    }
```

I've never had this before. It seems as though the dll isn't written properly to fit into the Microsoft namespace? Is that even possible?

Anyway, I've tried removing the reference and recreating it and restarting Visual Studio, but neither of these actions have worked.

Can anyone suggest a fix?

Comment: I guess Visual Studio shows you warnings mentioning why the reference cannot be resolved. Did you install the SDK, are all dependencies available?

Comment: I've had this sort of issue when referencing a DLL when using the a different version of .NET as my projects Target Framework. This has usually happened when I've attempted to reference a higher framework versioned DLL than my current Target Framework.

Comment: @StephenRoss that fixed it but now the cash drawer isn't opening lol different problem there

Comment: You can try flipping the "Copy Local" property on the reference, that can sometimes clear things like this up.

Answer (score 0):

As per the comment on the quesiton by @StephenRoss I changed the .NET Framework version that the project used and this fixed the problem.